# Where can I get wimax-tools?

Tags: intel-wireless

linuxwimax.org has been down for ages, is there anyway I can get the wimax daemon and wimax-tools so I can use my intel 6250?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the wimax tools at the following location:

- https://github.com/ago/wimax-tools

Comment: Too old. There's new one, v.1.4.5.